# Searching for an object inside a binary search tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

**The trace function is the one I am using to search through the binary search    tree it returns the right order of numbers when I search for something within the tree but when I want to see if a number doesn't exist i get segmentation fault  **

```
  // Binary search tree
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <assert.h>  
  using namespace std;

struct node
{
int data;
node * left;
node * right;
 };

 node * newNode(int data){
    node * newnode = new node();
 newnode -> data = data;
newnode -> left = NULL;
newnode -> right = NULL;
return newnode;
}


node* Insert (node * root, int data){
if(root == NULL){
root = newNode(data);
}
else if(data <= root-> data){
    root->left = Insert(root->left, data);
}
else{
    root -> right = Insert(root->right, data);
}
return root;
};

int Trace(node* root,int find){
node * searcher = root;
if(searcher->data == find){
    cout << searcher->data << endl;
}
else if(find <= root -> data){
    Trace(searcher->left, find);
    cout << searcher ->data<< endl;
}
else if(find >= root -> data){
    Trace(searcher->right, find);
    cout << searcher ->data << endl;

}
else cout << "not found" << endl;
return searcher-> data;
 };


 int main(){
node * root = NULL;   // creating an empty tree
root = Insert(root, 234234);
root = Insert(root, 2334);
root = Insert(root, 23784);
root = Insert(root, 223);
root = Insert(root, 4244);
root = Insert(root, 673234);
root = Insert(root, 2);
root = Insert(root, 2344);
root = Insert(root, 234);
Trace(root,4244);
return 0;


 }
```

Comment: Check your node in the second line of Trace-function: if (searcher == NULL) { /*Not found*/ }

Comment: @x1Mike7x I don't get what you are trying to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are walking through the tree looking for a member that doesn't exist, you'll eventually reach a NULL node. When you try to assess its data, you get a segmentation fault. You can avoid this by checking if the node you are going to assess is valid. For example, change your function Trace to:

```
int Trace(node* root, int find) {
    node * searcher = root;
    if(!searcher) {
        cout << "Node not found" << endl;
        //return something here
    }

    //rest of function stays the same
}
```